# Groovy cometd client LongPollingTransport.create() throws MissingMethodException

Tags: groovy, httpclient, cometd

My groovy Code :

```
import org.cometd.client.BayeuxClient;
import org.cometd.client.transport.ClientTransport;
import org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient as MyHttpClient    

def myurl = "http://192.168.11.170:8080/"

MyHttpClient httpClient = new MyHttpClient()

httpClient.start()

println (httpClient.GET(myurl).getStatus())

BayeuxClient client = new BayeuxClient(myurl, LongPollingTransport.create(null))
client.handshake()
client.waitFor(1000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED)
```

Here I am trying to make a `handshake`. It is just the documentation example code shown here https://docs.cometd.org/current/apidocs/org/cometd/client/BayeuxClient.html. But i am getting error shown below . Don't know What i am doing wrong ?

Output:

```
200
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.cometd.client.transport.LongPollingTransport.create() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
Possible solutions: grep(), terminate(), iterator(), accept(java.lang.String), accept(java.lang.String), print(java.lang.Object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadoc of `BayeuxClient` is completely out of sync with `LongPollingTransport` class - [there is no such method as `LongPollingTransport.create(arg)`](https://docs.cometd.org/current/apidocs/org/cometd/client/transport/LongPollingTransport.html).

Instead you could try using regular constructor of this class, e.g.

```
BayeuxClient client = new BayeuxClient(myurl, new LongPollingTransport([:], httpClient))
```

> *Reference: https://docs.cometd.org/current/apidocs/org/cometd/client/transport/LongPollingTransport.html#LongPollingTransport-java.util.Map-org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient-*

The first parameters is a map of options (empty in this example) and the second one is an instance of Jetty's `HttpClient` you import as `MyHttpClient`.